# Keras LSTM Training for MOCAP Data

Tags: python, keras

I want to train a RNN with LSTM which is used to estimate the future pose of human from mocap data.

The input of the network will be like
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7CI5.jpg)
 where each column represent one frame(time step) and the output is going to be a column vector with xyz coordinate of each body joint similar as each column of the [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7CI5.jpg) and it is one frame(time step) ahead. If I want the next output prediction, the input data should be the previous input data shift one time step ahead and concatenate the previous generated output.

The training data I have now is the coordinates of each body joint at each frame and I was not sure how I can train it with keras.

Comment: BTW, is there any restriction for the training data format of keras. Do I need to normalize the data what should it be normalized to?

Comment: Hello Jiaying Wang, welcome to the site. Could you provide the **code** and snips of the input **data** in the question? Also, in the future you can add to your question instead of commenting below, try to reserve that for answering questions from other users. And finally, could you be a little **more specific** about what specific issues you might be having?